# What is identifier in AWS Cognito Oauth Scope?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authorization, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

I have setup APIs and I am trying to use AWS Cognito User Pool for authorization and authentication. I am using custom domain in cognito (let's say: http://test-auth.abc.com). Domain name for API is (let's say: http://test-api.abc.com).
I am using postman and cURL to test these API endpoints.

When I don't select/check "**Allowed Custom Scopes**" the API tests work with *id_token*.

But when I select "**Allowed Custom Scopes**" and use *access token* I get "Unauthorized" error. (I use this scope in API gateway OAuth Scopes and I re-deployed the API before testing).

*Few more details*:

1. The name of the user pool is "user-api".
2. API name is "test APIs".
3. API "Authorizers" name is - "api test". I picked "user-api" for cognito.
4. Cognito >> Resource Servers >> identifier : http://test-api.abc.com
5. Scopes: name >> users.read

Why am I getting unauthorized error? Did I supply the right identifier?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, you can type any value for the "identifier".

My issue was I did not include "allowed custom scopes" along with "Allowed OAuth Scopes" in the token generation request.